# Allow for click only once, no double clicking

Tags: jquery

I need to have my submit button click only once to prevent double click.

Here is one method that somebody posted:

```
    $(document).ready(function () { 
      $("#submit").one('click', function (event) 
      {   
         event.preventDefault(); 
         //do something 
         $(this).prop('disabled', true); 
      }); 
    });
```

1) From my understanding, .one will be triggered only ONCE. 
If so, I am not sure what the need is for event.preventDefault() and  $(this).prop('disabled', true) as the click is done only once. This would be the fix in itself. From testing, I noticed that if I doubleclicked, it happened only once (tried without preventdefault and  disabling)

2) If .one didn't do what I assumed on 1), I understand the part of  $(this).prop('disabled', true); disabling the button but do not quite understand
why we need event.preventDefault(); From my understanding, it will prevent the default action, which in this case is the submission. If this is true, what good is the  event.preventDefault(); as we do want to submit it but only ONCE.

3) Won't the .one by itself prevent a double click. Am I correct on this? So no need for the rest of the logic, CORRECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whoever answered that must have considered fail-proof solution,

`event.preventDefault();`  - The purpose of implementing `.click` is to process form data before it get actually submitted. If you have `<input type="submit"` which would submit the form before executing the handler unless it is prevented.

`e.preventDefault()` is not required if you are using either `<button>` or `<input type="button"..`.

`$(this).prop('disabled', true);` - To prevent keyboard <kbd>space</kbd> equivalent to button click.

And `.one` will prevent double click.

Comment: question, say if you have a click on a button, the .one will do it only once, I got it. What happens though if after the click, the form is submitted and you are on the same page. will the .one again work as intended. Not that in my case, I go to another page after the click but what happens if you remain on the same page and merely want to submit the content?

Comment: @NatePet When form is submitted, page will refresh.. unless you do an ajax call.. so the `.one` will work as intended if the form is submitted(which will refresh the page).

Comment: Thanks for your response. What is the ideal solution then when using it with ajax?

Comment: I wouldn't submit form data using AJAX. but in case if you need to do so.. you can either 1. Change `.one` to `.on` and then use a flag `isSubmitted` inside click handler and set it to false.. and execute the handler only when `if (!isSubmitted)`. Set the flag back to true on AJAX success so that after submission your handler code will be executed. 2. Instead of flag, you can `.unbind/.off` and rebind on AJAX success using `.bind/.on`.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to me that he wants to prevent the default action of a submit button to be done, aka posting the form to the server.

Disabling the button itself makes it look grayish in most browsers so it's simply a direct indication that button has been clicked. Providing visual feedback of an action makes it more usable for an enduser.

So: the click of the button can be performed only once, hence the one, but he doesn't want the form to be submitted. Likely in the `//do something` he wants to make an ajax call or so.